# Check if date is not between two dates

Tags: java

I have sample code that check if date is NOT between two dates but I have no idea why it not works.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date d = sdf.parse("1900-01-01");
    Date s = sdf.parse("1990-01-01");
    Date e = sdf.parse("1990-01-02");

    if(d.before(s) || d.after(e)) {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("0");
    }
```

Result is **1** when I expect **0** .

Comment: It seems to be true that "1900-01-01" is before "1990-01-01" (of at least 90 years, I would say), so the first `if` is `true` :).

Comment: Hard to see... But yes, it is true. d is 1900, not 1990!

Comment: can you explain why you expecting 0 as first condition in your if statement is `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting a wrong value

```
if(d.before(s) || d.after(e)) { // d.before(s) is true
    System.out.println("1");
}
```

Then you will get 1

To satisfy your `if` condition either `d.before(s)=true` or `d.after(e)=true` or both should be `true`. In here `d.before(s)=true` then your `if` condition satisfied.

Comment: d.after(e) is false, it is the left condition the one that is true. d is 1900, and both s and e are 1990.

Comment: No, d.before(s) is true and d.after(e) is false, at least with the values he showed as example. Not worth an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(d.before(s) || d.after()) { 
        System.out.println("1");
    } //this is a true condition
```

---

Answer (score 1):

1900-01-01 is 90 years before 1990-01-01, hence one of the conditions is true and it outputs 1.